# How to convert for loop to multiple job submission?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I submit a job to cluster using qsub SubmitJob.sh. It works well but takes a long time to finish. Inside of SubmitJob.sh there is for loop which runs sequentially. I would like to convert my for loop for parallel job submission, such that each of them submits a single job (SubmitJob.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -V -cwd
#$ -e ./error.$JOB_NAME.$JOB_ID
#$ -o ./outpt.$JOB_NAME.$JOB_ID
#$ -l h_vmem=256g
##$ -q long
##$ -pe smp 4
#$ -l h_rt=24:00:00


cd /mydirectroy/

for ID in $(cat FilID.txt) ; do

Do_Somthing -n $ID  -o /OutputDirectory/$ID

done
```

Comment: High level idea, divide the contents of `FiLID.txt` into 4 parts, put the `for loop` into a function which will run the stuff in background using `&` . Feed the 4 parts of the file to the same function 4 times. In the end put `wait` to make sure everything is completed. This will be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this once or twice. The generic idea is that you supply parts of a array as reference to a function and execute it as child processes. I choose to use the square root as divider, because the work load will grow linear to the amount of items to process.

```
#! /bin/bash

FILE="FilID.txt"
DATA=($(cat ${FILE}))
AMOUNT=${#DATA[@]}
RANGE=$(echo "sqrt(${AMOUNT})" | bc)

echo ${amount}
echo $range

function _child {
        local -n numbers=$1
        echo "From ${numbers[0]} to ${numbers[-1]}"
        for n in ${numbers[@]}; do echo -n "$n, "; done
        echo 
}

for ((i=0; i<AMOUNT; i+=RANGE)) {
        part=(${DATA[@]:$i:$RANGE})
        _child part &
        # wait
}

wait
exit 0
```

You can test the script by populating FilID.txt as follows. Uncomment the `wait` in the for loop for readable output.

```
$ seq 0 98 > FilID.txt
```

You might want to wait until every N child processes are finished before you start the next batch. Back when I executed the script, the load became too high and Linux choose to kill our virtual development environment :p

P.S. if FilID.txt contain spaces with filenames you have to set `IFS=$'\n'` or something.